# Different logical addresses

Tags: c, operating-system

Why is it that when I run something like

```
int i;
printf("%p\n", &i);
```

I get different logical addresses each time I run it, shouldn't I get the same logical address that is then mapped onto different physical address each time I run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory is allocated to the variable or program  from the stack. So the memory is allocated is based on the free space available in the stack. When the program executes first some memory will allocate to that executing function. Next time we execute the same function , stack memory will have other some free memory. Simply Every time we run the program we will get the new stack address for that program.

Comment: @tommy_p1ckles: "Every time we run the program we will get the new stack address for that program" - this is not generally correct. Every time we run the program, the OS may load it into a different physical address, but the offset of the stack within the memory address space of the program remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable stored in stack based on the starting address of your function (main or other function). It's address fixed relatively to the function. Every time the program is executed, the main function will start with an arbitrary address.

Answer (score 0):

In each of the following cases, the memory address is constant throughout the execution of the program:

- A static local variable
- A static global variable
- A non-static global variable

The memory address of a local variable, on the other hand, depends on the state of the stack (the value of the SP register) at the point in the execution of the program when the function is called.